# TextMate is not loading my bundle from git

Tags: git, textmatebundles

Using git, I checked out

MyBundle.tmbundle

to

/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles

but TextMate does not recognize the bundle.

I tried reloading TextMate and running "Reload Bundles" in the menu.  None of this works.

The same bundle had worked before.  I manually deleted it and tried installing it.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I remade the bundle from scratch, recommitted it, and checked it out again.  The keys in bundle changed.  I think that somehow TextMate corrupted, lost, or blacklisted those old keys when it crashed.  I am not sure why it had previously crashed.  Anyways, it works now.  Moral of the story - other TextMate files corrupted when it crashed, which prevented it from recognizing the bundle.  The bundle however was exactly the same because it was on saved in a git repo.